# Rolling Java upgrade in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, java-7, java-6

we are currently running Apache Cassandra 1.2.13 on 4 machines having Java 6 and are planning to upgrade Java to version 7.
Is it possible to do a rolling Java upgrade in a running cluster, i.e. node by node?
I know that Thrift protocols for client-server communication are incompatible for Java versions 6 & 7. How does that apply to the internal server-server communication within a cluster?

I haven't found any mentioning about that in the documentation or other sources.

Comment: Why change java's version on a working (assumingly) production environment ?

Comment: Moreover I'd say that your best option is to test by stopping gracefully one of your instances, make the update, start it back and see if replication and gossip tend to work.
Afterward it would be marvellous to share your results with us :)

Comment: Cassandra 1.2 supports both Java 6 and 7 (newer than 1.6.0_29 and 1.7.0_25): http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/install/installJreDeb.html